# How to remove the syncing attribute from Nautilus icons?

Tags: nautilus

A while ago I used a software that syncs folders.

I already removed it a while ago but since my Nautilus icons keep showing this syncing flavor.

How can I refresh the icons and get rid of this syncing attribute?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you make your title more specific? To refresh nautilus icons, one presses the F5 key, but that is not what you ask in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it works. It depends on the theme you are using.

1. Right click on the folder.
2. Click on the folder icon.
3. In the dialog go to `/usr/share/icons/<your theme>/<size>/places/` and select the default folder's icon .

Comment: Thanks. Any more updated way? It affects all folders.

Comment: @orschiro sorry, what you mean by *"It affects all folders"*?

Comment: All folders in Nautilus have this syncing attribute.